# Dynamically changing global variables in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

How to set a global bool variable that can be accessed in all classes ? its value can be changed based on runtime conditions.

Comment: You've got conflicting requirements. A _constant_, as the name implies, cannot be changed at runtime. You probably want a _global variable_ with a default value instead, though it's hard to tell what you're actually trying to accomplish. Maybe a function would be better. So, please **edit your question** and clarify what you are trying to solve (what is this value used for/how do you want to use it).

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you already have to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the *property on a singleton* approach proposed by @MiteshDobareeya is a useful solution and solves the same problem, it's actually not a *global variable*.

A *global variable* is a top-level variable that everyone may access:

```
Foo.h:

extern SomeType globalVariableName;
// For example:
extern NSString * globalString;
extern BOOL globalBool;


Foo.m

// This is at the top-level, outside any @implementation !
// You need this once in your app to actually define the
// variables values.
SomeType globalVariableName = initialValue;
NSString * globalString = @"Zoobar";
BOOL globalBool = YES;


SomeOther.m

#import "Foo.h"

- (void)foo {
    // You can access the variable in any Objective-C method
    // or even C function.
    if (globalBool) {
        [self doSomething];
    }
}
```

Comment: will this global variable 'globalBool' have only one instance throughout the application? If I edit it in one class, will it be reflected in other classes too?

Comment: you need to refactor it globally in each file.

Comment: @Jeyanthu: Yes, it's just one instance throughout the application. Manipulating it in one place will also "update" in any other place as they are accessing the same thing.

Comment: @holex: What do you mean with "you need to refactor it globally in each file" ?

Comment: @DarkDust: Thanks a lot. Will try this.

Comment: @DarkDust, he asked about editing the global variable... if he want to edit the variable name, he needs to refactor it in every single file or place when he uses it – this question _" If I edit it in one class, will it be reflected in other classes too?"_ in meaning of "if I set the variable at one class the value would be updated in other class" makes no sense, as we are talking about _global_ variables from the very beginning, that meaning would have been kinda stupid from the OP in that context, would not it have?

Comment: @DarkDust: Will these extern variables retain their values on app crash/ termination or killing the app?

Comment: @holex:Sorry. I dint mean editing the variable name. i meant modifying the value only.

Comment: @Jeyanthu: No, they will not retain their value on app exit.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely **would not** go for any of the suggested solutions, which is based on pure ANSI-C solutions or logically incorrectly recommending using the app-delegate as a global model, but I would create a *singleton* class on your model-layer, which can store any property during runtime for you.

even if that is technically not a *global variable* – it would rather make more sense in any project than applying a *pure* global variable in some random class which does not really belong to the actual global variable.

---

#### RuntimeEnvironment.h

```
@interface RuntimeEnvironment : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedEnvironment;

@property (nonatomic, getter=isSwitchOn) BOOL switch;

@end
```

#### RuntimeEnvironment.m

```
@implementation RuntimeEnvironment

+ (instancetype)sharedEnvironment {
    static id _sharedInstance = nil;
    @synchronized([self class]) {
        if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
            _sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

---

#### in action:

set the variable:

```
[RuntimeEnvironment sharedEnvironment].switch = TRUE;
```

or read its current value:

```
BOOL _myGlobalSwitch = [RuntimeEnvironment sharedEnvironment].isSwitchOn;
```

---

this solution is easy to maintain or extend as your project is growing (it will), and you are also doing the proper encapsulation for everything in one place, on your model, correctly.

Comment: Minor comment: [avoid `@synchronized`](http://perpendiculo.us/2009/09/synchronized-nslock-pthread-osspinlock-showdown-done-right/) (old but still relevant article) because it's very slow. Use the modern `dispatch_once` approach instead. Also, while I'd also prefer your solution, would you mind elaborating what you think is wrong with the global variable approach (since you strongly say that you would _definitely_ not use that approach: other than a personal preference and missing KVO I don't see a reason).

Comment: @DarkDust, the `@synchronized` keyword is perfect for beginners who have no idea about multi-threading or GCD but wants to create the correct and reasonably readable code – like the OP in our case.

Comment: What's so hard about `dispatch_once` to grasp? _Do it once in the app lifecycle, then skip it on repeated calls._ I'd argue that's easier to understand than _"you need lock this code because of potential multithreading issues"_.

Comment: @DarkDust, for you probably nothing because you are an advanced developer, but on the market neither understanding of multi-threading nor synchronising threads are expected from a _trainee_ or a _junior_ developer; and between us, we won't even need to mention the amateur hobby developers, who could not even set up a _global_ variable in their project (and also needles to mention how much messy such project would be at the end of the day) – for these guys the OOP or MVC are just extra pain in their ass, and nearly all of them have limited intention to understand those. :(

Answer (score 1):

Declare your bool variable in AppDelegate.h

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL *isBOOL;
```

Then create app delegate shared application object in your view controller implementation file and assign it as a shared application object in viewdidload.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
{
   AppDelegate *appdel;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 appdel=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Now you can access that isBOOL variable in every class by creating appdelegate shared application object and also you can change variable value based on your conditions.

```
 appdel.isBOOL=YES/NO;
```

Comment: Instead of creating instance variables everywhere, it'd be nicer to create a singleton getter on your `AppDelegate` class like this: `+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate { return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] };` Then you can simply do `[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] isBOOL]` wherever you want.

Comment: Use the AppDelegate only for things that have to do with running the application as a whole. Don't use it to deposit any old stuff that you want. Unless this _is_ about the whole application, put it into a suitable file.

Comment: I would not use the app-delegate as a global model – it is not the app-delegate's purpose at all.

Comment: You can also define it in prefixheader file.